# How to get all nicknames from audit log of a user in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get all the nicknames from audit logs in a list in the rewrite version of discord.py

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. I can point you in the right direction. The actual code you will have to write yourself.
When you are stuck, come back with a specific question.

You need to iterate over `audit_logs`, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit%20log#discord.Guild.audit_logs

To get the audit events for nickname change you need to filter the `action` for `discord.AuditLogAction.member_update`, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit%20log#discord.AuditLogAction.member_update

The AuditLogEntry has an `before` and `after`, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit%20log#discord.AuditLogEntry.before
These are instances of AuditLogDiff of which you can access the nickname, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit%20log#discord.AuditLogDiff.nick

Comment: I know how to loop through audit log entries but I dont know how to specify that the member update is nickname change, if I figure that out then its solved for me